# Unexpected end of JSON input in vs code when trying to retrieve org browser metadata

Tags: vs-code, developer-org

When i am trying to retrieve Org browser metadata through vs code i am getting this error.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

I have created package with manifest,authorized my org and set default org as well.

[image: Syntax error]

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: No @PooyaPanahandeh

Comment: I just changed from 7.188 to new version 2 and my problem is solved now.